# Increase size of spacing between cells in collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, cell

I want different spacing between my cells inside my collectionview.

My collectionview contains only one section. I know it's possible to change the spacing between sections but I'll like between cells.

I would like the spacing to be greater between the centered cell and its sides, and that the spacing of the other cells do not move. Basically, my white circle does not touch the edges of neighboring cells without changing all the spacing.

Image of my problem here :

[image: Image of my problem here]

There is a solution ?

Comment: @the4kman No because if I use this method collectionView:layout:minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex specified in this topic, the spacing modified affects all the cells

Answer (score 1):

You could implement this method in your view controller: `collectionView:layout:minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex`

Comment: Hi, yeah but I only have one section who contain my cells it's like collectionView:layout:minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt I can't modify specific spacing. thank for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating 3 different sections.

1. **1st Section** - section containing cells before the larger cell, with `inter item spacing as 10`
2. **2nd Section** - section containing the larger cell, with `section insets as (top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 20)`
3. **3rd section** - section containing cells after the larger cell, with `inter item spacing as 10`

You can change the values as per your requirements.

Here is what the code says:

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
{
    return 3
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    if section == 1
    {
        return 1
    }
    return 2
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    if indexPath.section == 1
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    if indexPath.section == 1
    {
        return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
    return CGSize(width: 82, height: 82)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat
{
    if section == 1
    {
        return 0
    }
    return 5
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets
{
    if section == 1
    {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 20)
    }
    return .zero
}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Let me know if you still face any issues.

Comment: Thank you for the tip I will work on it and I will come back to you for the final result :)

Comment: Sure. Accept the answer if you get it working. Happy Coding .